# Auto Exponent. Can this be turned off?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am importing data into Excel from a database application for ease of editing. The data has a field with room numbers such as; 1N01, 1S01, 1W01 and 1E01. Excel converts all of the 1Exx room numbers to numbers. Example; 1E01 becomes 10, 1E05 becomes 100000, etc.

Can I turn this feature off or get around it somehow?

Comment: How are you doing the import?  There should be a way to define what data types you're working with so Excel will see 1E01 as text instead of trying to do the exponent work on it.

Comment: When you say it changes then, do you mean it change the value in the cell, or just what is displayed. If you click on a cell with the E101, and look in the formula bar, what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

When you import the data, tell the *Import Wizard* the the field is *Text*.

[image]